# how to change css during holidays with php or Javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I really would like to know if it's possible to change the style.css during the holidays in WordPress with PHP or Javascript.

so when it's Christmas Day, i want to change my style.css to christmas.css.
But when Christmas is over i want to turn it back to the default style.css.

```
Normal Day       ---->    style.css
Christmas Day    ---->    christmas.css
After Christmas ---->    style.css
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Psuedo: `if day = 25 december` -> `link christmas.css` else -> `link style.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the CSS file with PHP then you can add a check that gets the date and changes it accordingly, as so:

```
$date = date("m-d");
if ($date == "12-25") {
  /* Include christmas.css here */
} else {
  /* Include style.css here */
}
```

Comment: Both are right but i need to give it Keydose for the fast responds.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` of your webpage, you could use this:

Change the `$date` to `'11-21'` to verify that it works.

```
<?php
  $date = date("m-d");

  if($date = '12-25') {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/christmas.css">';
  } else {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Both are right but i need to give it Keydose for the fast responds.